# mongoose - .catch doesn't catch the error

Tags: mongoose

the first .catch statement doesn't catch because if the wrong task_id is entered the returned value is null and not an error. Can someone show me how to properly handle this error?

```
 router.get("/tasks/:task_id", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
   (User.findById(req.user.id)
      .then(user => res.json(user.tasks.id(req.params.task_id)))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).send({ tasknotfound: "No matching task found" }))
    ).catch(err =>
      res.status(404).json({ usernotfound: "No user found" })
)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when we hit this route, first we use our middleware to ensure authentication is in place, right? After that, we have our callback, etc ...
So what I like to do here (we're talking about the error handling)is to make an empathy error array. Afterward, I do make checks. Here we're checking if there's a username and a task present in our `reg.body` and if there's something missing, we push an object with the custom error messages. After that, we check if the errors array is greater than 0 and if it is we render those error(s). On the other hand, if everything went well what we want to do is use that data, assign it to an object, save it to our DB, show the user a success message of some sorts, and potentially redirect the user to an appropriate route. `Task` would be a `Mongoose model`. I used the `Express router` approach, and that `ensureAuthenticated` is just a middleware name I gave. `Passport.js` that you're using is awesome. I wrote this by following your code and show you how I would do it. Sidenote: I usually use [connect-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash) for displaying my success/ error messages.
`npm install connect-flash`

```
 router.post('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {

  let errors = [];

  if(!req.body.username){
    errors.push({text:'Please add a username'});
  }
  if(!req.body.task){
    errors.push({text:'Please add some tasks'});
  }

  if(errors.length > 0){
    res.render('/add', {
      errors: errors,
      title: req.body.username,
      details: req.body.tasks
    });
  } else {
    const newTask = {
      username: req.body.username,
      tasks: req.body.tasks,
      id: req.user.id
    }
    new Task(newTask)
      .save()
      .then(task => {
        req.flash('success_msg', 'Your task has been added');
        res.redirect('/tasks');
      })
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for clearing this up for me, i was under the assumption because the catch statements were in a different scope it would catch different errors. 

Your code makes it more legible but it's still returning null if the task id doesn't exist. instead of returning the the tasknotfound message. i think it has to do with the way the individual tasks are being found and returned. maybe i can set it to a variable and if the block `user.tasks.id(req.params.task_id)` returns null i can just send the error instead? I'm still having trouble accomplishing this though

Comment: I'll update my answer to show you how I do, okay? :)

Comment: thanks for helping out, I found a way to directly search for sub docs in another stack question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467452/is-it-possible-to-query-subdocuments-directly-using-mongoose using one of these methods my search now returns an error because it doesn't return null anymore if its an invalid id.

Comment: Really? Well, that's great. But still go and look at my approach and if you like it, appreciate the effort, at least make an upvote. I really went in *:)*

Comment: most deff, I do appreciate the help. :D! i might just use this for my post route instead haha!

Comment: It's a solid approach, so you might as well accept my answer. I'll be here if you get stuck on something else **:)** Have a good one, buddy.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to read but it works, searches for subdocs directly returns an array of objects, then in the `.then` statement return a JSON of the first object in the array, this way if the id doesn't exist it will actually throw an err to be caught.

```
router.get("/tasks/:task_id", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
   (User.findOne({ "tasks._id": req.params.task_id }, { "tasks.$": 1 })
       .then(task =>res.json(task.tasks[0]))
       .catch(err => res.status(404).send({ tasknotfound: "No matching task found" }))
)
 .catch(err =>
      res.status(404).json({ usernotfound: "No user found" })
 )
})
```